# VBA: Error with in an error handler

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a problem with my error handler. I have a script that gains access to a site and downloads a few files. I want to implement an error handler for it because a change to the site could cause errors to be thrown. This is my error handler.

```
IEError:
    TxtLog ExtractErrLogDir, Environ("UserName") & " " & Now() & " " & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description ' this is a function I made that writes to txt files
    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    MsgBox "Auto Extract Stop Working:" & vbNewLine & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Also, How I make a new instance of IE.

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

The problem I have is I have no way to tell if the Internet explorer instance I made is closed or not for my error handler. So I attempted to make an error handler with in the error handler. To close IE and if it errors on that ignore it and move to next line. But its not working correctly `IE.Quit` will still throw and error out side of the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an error is thrown within a routine, you need the call `Resume` before setting up a new error-handling mechanism. Try it this way:

```
IEError:
    TxtLog ExtractErrLogDir, Environ("UserName") & " " & Now() & " " & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description ' this is a function I made that writes to txt files
    Resume TryQuit ' <-- call Resume to be able to setup new err-handling

TryQuit:
    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    MsgBox "Auto Extract Stop Working:" & vbNewLine & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: lol you beat me to it. BTW `TryQuit:` should be before else the `Resume` looses it's meaning ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout by 00:01:09 ;). Well that's not a problem because we dont want to break the sequence it's only a matter of invoking `Resume`, to permit new err-Handling. Isn't it? So it's just a way of *tricking* VBA :)

Comment: What I meant is If you have `TryQuit:` immediately  after  `IEError:` then you do not need `Resume`

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's precisely the point: without putting this additional label and the `Resume TryQuit` statement, the next `On Error Resume Next` will not be effective, and any error thrown by `IE.Quit` will break the code ignoring the resume-next.

Comment: One question will `Resume` clear the error code? What I mean by that is for this line in your example. `MsgBox "Auto Extract Stop Working:" & vbNewLine & Err.Description`. Will the `Err.Description` be the `IE.Quit` error or the error that triggered the `IEError:` handler? I hope that is clear for you.

Comment: @Quint yes as soon as you invoke `Resume` the Error status is cleared, **and also** you will be able to setup a new `On Error do something` mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it

```
LetsContinue:
    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    MsgBox "Auto Extract Stop Working:" & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
IEError:
    TxtLog ExtractErrLogDir, Environ("UserName") & " " & Now() & " " & _
    Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    
    Resume LetsContinue
```

To create a new instance of IE using `Late Binding`, use this

```
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
```

To create a new instance of IE using `Early Binding`, use this. You will need to set the reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
```

**EDIT**

> What is the advantage of Dim IE As New InternetExplorer vs how I have it? – Quint 12 mins ago

`InternetExplorerMedium` was first used way back when `Vista` and `IE8` was launched to create an instance of Internet Explorer running at a medium integrity level.

I see no need of it in today's era.

See the remarks section from this [MSDN KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **Remarks**
>
> Windows Internet Explorer 8. On Windows Vista, to create an instance of Internet Explorer running at a medium integrity level, pass CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium (defined in exdisp.idl) to CoCreateInstance. The resulting InternetExplorerMedium object supports the same events, methods, and properties as the InternetExplorer object.

I am not sure, how did I forget to mention this but instead of using `On Error Resume Next` you can also do this

```
LetsContinue:
    If Not IE Is Nothing Then
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
    End If
    '~~> Not sure what is the below line for but I have still included it
    MsgBox "Auto Extract Stop Working:" & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
IEError:
    TxtLog ExtractErrLogDir, Environ("UserName") & " " & Now() & " " & _
    Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    
    Resume LetsContinue
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `Dim IE As New InternetExplorer` vs how I have it?

Comment: I have incorporated that in my answer for future visitors as well. You may have to refresh the page to see the edit.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention something. I have added that as well at the end of the post

Comment: I didnt even think of checking what `IE` is set to. Good catch. Thank you for your well thought our answer.